# Portable encoding of 32 bit integers to communicate with an 8 bit device

Tags: c, encoding, portability, 8-bit

I need to communicate with an 8 bit device on which there is no nthol function. It is also impossible to use protocol buffers library.

Will following C function produce the same output string no matter on what architecture it is run (different endianness, different number of bits):

```
void encode(uint32_t input, unsigned char* buf, int buf_len) {
  assert(sizeof(uint32_t) <= buf_len);
  buf[0] = input >> 24 & 0xFF;
  buf[1] = input >> 16 & 0xFF;
  buf[2] = input >> 8 & 0xFF;
  buf[3] = input & 0xFF;
}
```

Will following function correctly read such encoded string and produce the same result on all architectures:

```
void decode(const unsigned char* buf, int buf_len, uint32_t* output) {
  assert(sizeof(uint32_t) <= buf_len);
  *output = buf[0];
  *output <<= 8;
  *output |= buf[1];
  *output <<= 8;
  *output |= buf[2];
  *output <<= 8;
  *output |= buf[3];
}
```

Is it possible that on an 8 bit processor 32 bit integers won't be handled correctly for some reason?

Comment: Have you considered using [`htons`](http://www.beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/htonsman.html)?

Comment: @tenfour It's a 32-bit number, so it would have to be `htonl`. And it is stated in the question that the 8-bit system doesn't have `ntohl` so I doubt it has `htonl`.

Comment: I'm terrible - I even read the question twice and missed that :(

Comment: "the same output string". A silly quibble: it's not an output *string*, because a string in C means a 0-terminated sequence of non-0 bytes, and this isn't that. Everyone knew what you meant, so it doesn't matter here. If you document that these functions read/write a "string" there's a small chance you'll confuse someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that looks fine. A couple of comments:

1. You should use `uint8_t` instead of assuming `unsigned char` is 8-bit, when the code relies on that fact.
2. It would be a bit cleaner (imo) to do the receive using a local variable, so you don't have to shift through the pointer to `output` all the time.
3. You can probably just return the decoded value, making the `decode()` function a bit cleaner.

-

```
 uint32_t decode(const uint8_t *buf, size_t buf_len) {
   uint32_t out = 0;
   assert(sizeof out <= buf_len);
   out |= buf[0];
   out <<= 8;
   out |= buf[1];
   out <<= 8;
   out |= buf[2];
   out <<= 8;
   out |= buf[3];
   return out;
 }
```

Comment: I don't think the code does rely on `unsigned char` being 8 bit. Obviously if the reader and writer have different sizes of `CHAR_BIT` then there's an issue, how were the values widened/narrowed when they moved from one system to the other. Let's hope they were zero-extended not sign-extended. But otherwise the questioner's code works fine with `CHAR_BIT != 8`, doesn't it? Your code (intentionally) doesn't compile at all when `CHAR_BIT != 8`, but I don't think you need to be so cautious.

Comment: Oops, my mistake. The "proper code" doesn't rely on char being 8 bits, but the assert does. The test is otherwise insufficient because 4 bytes are required regardless of the value of `CHAR_BIT`, whereas `sizeof(uint32_t)` might be less than 4. Still, it would be just as good to fix the assert as to use `uint8_t`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will work. The C shift operator will do the right thing no matter which endianess or word-size the machine has.

Just remember to do the exact same thing in all programs communicating with this protocol.